# visual studio 2017 no inicia app web en modo depuracion

Tags: visual-studio

tengo una aplicación en VS2017 Comunity Edition, la cual esta diseñada en capas (WEB, ENT, DAL, BLL). pues bien, hasta hace unos días, en uno de los equipos en el cual estoy desarrollando, comenzó a poner problemas al iniciar la aplicación en modo depuración (F5), ya que se queda eternamente esperando al navegador para que inicie la pagina definida en RouteConfig.cs.
dado que jamas se ejecutaba, probe iniciarla con Ctrl+F5 la cual se ejecuta sin problemas, aunque claro, no me permite depurar la app.
haciendo algunas pruebas, me percate que esto sucede al agregar la capa BLL (negocio) como referencia en la app Web (MVC). Para cerciorarme de esto, inicie otra app web nueva (sin referencias) y se ehjecuta sin problemas en modi depuracion.
Esta solucion (todas las capas) la teste nuevamente en otro equipo con VS2017 Comunity Edition, pero no presenta este mismo problema. Alguna idea de porque pueda estar pasando esto?.
Nota: esto solo ocurre con crome, ya que probe con firefox y no se da este problema
Saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a Deshabilitar la depuración de Chrome:
Herramientas->Opciones 
Depuración->General->Habilitar Depuración de JavaScript para ASP.Net(IE y Chrome) deshabilitado.